# VScode file reference is obscured

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I´m new new to both VScode and angular.
In my newly downloaded VScode and angular 5 app, I have the Hello World page in index.html. Now I would like to have an iframe that points to a file in the same folder. Problem is that VScode cannot see this test.html file, even though it´s in the same folder. When I run the page, the iframe content is just a copy of the parent page´s content. Quite weird. 
when I control click the test.html link in the iframe, VScode tells me that the file does not exist, but it can create it for me. When I choose this, it creates the test.html in C:\test.html - even weirder!?

What am I missing here?

Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: ./test.html maybe?

Comment: It´s the same :(